# Visual Studio for Mac couldn't open any files in any solution

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I'm having wierd problem with Visual Studio for Mac community version 7.4.2.(build 12).

Every files I try to open I get error message and the files couldn't be open.

The error message is

=============================================

The file 'some file.cs' could not be opened.

Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: theFont

==============================================

It happened just this morning. It was just fine last night.

I cannot open any files in any solution.

When I open the files in the other text editor, it looks fine.

I googled it but couldn't find a solution.

If you have any idea please give me a comment.

I'm now updating my VisualStudio for mac application to alpha version hoping it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. What I did was go to preferences in Visual Studio and changed the font to a different font. It worked after that. You mileage may vary though.

Comment: English is not my first language. so I couldn't do much here but just searching the answers.. I hope my english get better to do some answering or helping the other people. thank you!!!